# Applied image filter to images using core graphics in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-image

I have used core graphics to display images in greyscale in tableview. But the table is scrolling very slowly.Is there any solution by which i can speed up the scrolling.

Comment: does the image come from an external url? is it embedded in your bundle?

Comment: the image is in my bundle. Ia m using core graphics to display image in greyscale in cellforrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to follow these steps:

1. let's say you have an array of images prepared in your `viewDidLoad`, called `originalImages`.
2. inside your `viewDidLoad`, you have to scroll all the `originalImages` applying to each image the gray scale filter and appending the new image inside a new array called `grayScaleImages`.
3. use such `grayScaleImages` as pivot for your `UITableViewDataSource` (and delegate).

A very rough example might be:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    var originalImages:[UIImage]?
    var grayScaleImages:[UIImage]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // load original images
        self.originalImages = [UIImage]() 
        //... load whatever here (eg: from bundle) ...

        // load gray scale images
        self.grayScaleImages = [UIImage]()
        self.originalImages?.forEach { image in
            let grayScaleImage = image.applyGrayScale()
            self.grayScaleImages?.append(grayScaleImage)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.grayScaleImages?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellID", for: indexPath)
        cell.imageView?.image = self.grayScaleImages?[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func applyGrayScale() -> UIImage {
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")!
        filter.setValue(CIImage(image: self), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let output = filter.outputImage!
        let cgImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)!
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }
}
```

Comment: will this login work when images are being downloaded from the internet?

Comment: Yes it works, but you will have to implement some more tricks.